# Can I use a LockService across two functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The [LockService documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) states that I can lock access to one section of code, but with if there are two functions which access the same sheet in my SpreadSheet?

Is there a way to stop both functions trying to access that sheet concurrently?

Right now my work around is to set and unset a script property via the Properties Service:

```
{
  'lock': True
}
```

The problem here of course, is that if one of my functions fails midway the lock state will be permanently in place.

**EDIT**

Upon the request of commenters here is some pseudocode for the two functions in question

```
SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActive.getSheetByName('Sheet 1')

// clock trigger to run this once every 5 minutes
function funcA() {
  range = SHEET.getRange('C2:E')
  vals = range.getValues();
  updatedVals = doSomeProcessing(vals);
  range.setValues(vals);
}

// clock trigger to run this once every 6 hours
function funcB() {
  range = SHEET.getRange('A2:Z')
  vals = range.getValues();
  updateVals = doSomeOtherProcessing(vals);
  range.setValues(vals);
  sheet.sort(1);
}
```

So the problem is if `funcA` reads from `SHEET`, then `funcB` sorts, then `funcA` writes back to `SHEET`. (and there are probably other possible issues).

Comment: How are the two functions called?

Comment: Can please you post the functions code?

Comment: @Alessandro I've added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach

During concurrent access to a shared resource you can use Apps Script LockService to prevent race conditions.

Here a simple example on with your two functions `funcA` and `funcB`:

```
// this function takes 10 seconds to run, waits 5 seconds for the lock to be released otherwise it fails.
function funcA() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); // gets the lock from the LockService 
  try {
    lock.waitLock(5000); // Tries for at most 5 seconds to get the lock
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('funcA could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
}

// this functions takes 20 seconds to run, waits 5 seconds for the lock to be released otherwise it fails.
function funcB() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(5000);
    Utilities.sleep(20000);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('funcB could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
}
```

You can try easily the lock behavior calling function A right after function B.

### Reference:

[LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitLock(Integer))

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise the lock had a wider scope than the current function.