# Is there a way to cache doPost requests?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that flattens the contents of a JSON object [function 'parser'] and another that pastes the flattened results to the last row of a Google Sheet [function 'writePayload']. Each of these functions are called in doPost(e) as follows:

```
function doPost(e){
  var data = e.postData.contents;
  var output = parser(data);
  writePayload(output);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
}
```

The challenge I am having is that I will occasionally get post requests in such a short period of time, the writePayload function overwrites the contents of the first payload. The writePayload function looks for the last row on a sheet, then pastes contents starting at the last row. When posts are made in a short period of time, both payloads will be written starting at the same row causing some data loss.

Is there a timer or cache function I can use to prevent data from overwriting when post requests are made in rapid succession?

Comment: Have considered [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock?hl=en) There is also a [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

For more context about [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock?hl=en) as mentioned by **Cooper** on the comments, perhaps you can try this sample Lock Service approach below:

> This script was derived from the similar post answer [Can I use a LockService across two functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61873247/15384825)

```
function mainFunction() {
  functionOne(); //run for 30 seconds
  functionTwo(); //run for 30 seconds
}

function functionOne(){
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(5000); // Tries for at most 5 seconds to get the lock
    Utilities.sleep(30000); // e.g. run for 30 seconds
    Logger.log("Function 1  has finished running at: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"));
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('function 1 could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
}

function functionTwo(){
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(5000);
    Utilities.sleep(30000); // e.g. run for 30 seconds
    Logger.log("Function 2 has finished running at: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"));
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('function 2 could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }
}
```

### Log result:

[image]

> The 2 functions has 30 seconds difference in running time